# Why is child class not calling constructor of parent class?

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor

From php.net

> If the child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared as private).

From what I understand if I do not define a constructor in a child, the parent's constructor will be called.

For example, I've made a parent class, with constructor. Instantiated both child and parent class, however it throws the following warning:
**Warning: Missing argument 1 for vehicle::__construct()**

Example code:

```
class vehicle{
    protected $type;
    function __construct($type){
        $this->type = $type;
        echo "Type chosen: $this->type";
    }
}

class car extends vehicle{

}

$vehicle = new vehicle("sport");
$car = new car;
```

Comment: Because `vehicle` has a __mandatory__ argument in its constructor, which means that `car` has the same mandatory argument..... but you're trying to instantiate a `car` without that argument, so it calls the parent constructor and gives you an error because you haven't passed that argument when trying to instantiate it

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @axiac I thought it'd call the parent constructor automatically without throwing error since i'm already supplying argument to parent constructor

Comment: `$car = new car;` Where is the argument to the constructor?

Comment: You're not supplying __any__ argument to the parent constructor..... just because you're instantiated __one__ object of the parent type already, doesn't mean that __all other instances__ of that parent, or that inherit from that parent will inherit that value..... it's __classes__ that inherit, not __instances__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is calling constructor of parent class. And as you are not supplying any arguments for constructor, when you declare `$car` object, it's giving you warning about missing parameter.

You should have initialize child class object by supplying "type" argument as per follow:

```
$car = new car("family");
```